# Unable to echo json data in PHP

Tags: php, json

This is my Json code with PHP output

```
$buffer = '[{"isSuccess":"true","message":"Consignment Number Valid","orderReferenceIdList":[":Succesfull"],"tracking_Details":[{"BookingDate":"02-05-2020","Destination":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Origin":"LAHORE","Shipper":"VESTURE MERCHANDISING (OTURE)","Consignee":"Syed Asad Abbas Bokhari","ServiceType":"Overnight","CNStatus":"DELIVERED","CNStatusID":"55","pieces":"1","weight":"0.5","Details":[{"DateTime":"5/5/2020 12:03:59 PM","Status":"Delivered","Location":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Detail":"Shipment has been Delivered. Delivery Date & Time May 5 2020 1:11AM and Received By: ASAD"},{"DateTime":"5/5/2020 10:03:58 AM","Status":"On Delivery","Location":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Detail":"Shipment is Out for Delivery."},{"DateTime":"5/4/2020 10:43:51 AM","Status":"On Delivery","Location":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Detail":"Shipment is Out for Delivery."},{"DateTime":"5/4/2020 10:06:57 AM","Status":"Unloading","Location":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Detail":"Shipment has arrived at hub."},{"DateTime":"5/4/2020 3:55:10 AM","Status":"Loading","Location":"GUJRANWALA","Detail":"Shipment has departed."},{"DateTime":"5/2/2020 11:20:44 PM","Status":"Unloading","Location":"Lahore Airport","Detail":"Shipment has arrived at hub."},{"DateTime":"5/2/2020 10:40:33 PM","Status":"Loading","Location":"KOT LAKH PAT","Detail":"Shipment has departed."},{"DateTime":"5/2/2020 8:30:52 PM","Status":"Arrived at OPS","Location":"LAHORE","Detail":"Shipment has arrived at origin facility."},{"DateTime":"5/2/2020 12:00:00 AM","Status":"Booking","Location":"LAHORE","Detail":"Shipment is booked."}]}]}]1';

$data = json_decode($buffer, true);

foreach ($data['tracking_Details'] as $a) {
echo $a['BookingDate'];
}
```

This is a JSON beautifier online tool result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwJx5.png

But the output of echo is nothing. How can I output JSON in PHP?

Comment: You might want to remove the last char `1` from your `$buffer`, making it valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json formate is wrong. end of the string there is 1. i have remove that. try the following code

```
$buffer = '[{"isSuccess":"true","message":"Consignment Number Valid","orderReferenceIdList":[":Succesfull"],"tracking_Details":[{"BookingDate":"02-05-2020","Destination":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Origin":"LAHORE","Shipper":"VESTURE MERCHANDISING (OTURE)","Consignee":"Syed Asad Abbas Bokhari","ServiceType":"Overnight","CNStatus":"DELIVERED","CNStatusID":"55","pieces":"1","weight":"0.5","Details":[{"DateTime":"5/5/2020 12:03:59 PM","Status":"Delivered","Location":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Detail":"Shipment has been Delivered. Delivery Date & Time May 5 2020 1:11AM and Received By: ASAD"},{"DateTime":"5/5/2020 10:03:58 AM","Status":"On Delivery","Location":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Detail":"Shipment is Out for Delivery."},{"DateTime":"5/4/2020 10:43:51 AM","Status":"On Delivery","Location":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Detail":"Shipment is Out for Delivery."},{"DateTime":"5/4/2020 10:06:57 AM","Status":"Unloading","Location":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Detail":"Shipment has arrived at hub."},{"DateTime":"5/4/2020 3:55:10 AM","Status":"Loading","Location":"GUJRANWALA","Detail":"Shipment has departed."},{"DateTime":"5/2/2020 11:20:44 PM","Status":"Unloading","Location":"Lahore Airport","Detail":"Shipment has arrived at hub."},{"DateTime":"5/2/2020 10:40:33 PM","Status":"Loading","Location":"KOT LAKH PAT","Detail":"Shipment has departed."},{"DateTime":"5/2/2020 8:30:52 PM","Status":"Arrived at OPS","Location":"LAHORE","Detail":"Shipment has arrived at origin facility."},{"DateTime":"5/2/2020 12:00:00 AM","Status":"Booking","Location":"LAHORE","Detail":"Shipment is booked."}]}]}]';

$data = json_decode($buffer, true);
if(isset($data[0]['tracking_Details']) && !empty($data[0]['tracking_Details'])){        
    foreach ($data[0]['tracking_Details'] as $a) {
        echo $a['BookingDate'];
    }
}
```

Output :

```
02-05-2020
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works, but the issue is I am getting JSON data using courier API, and then return the data which has string 1 in the last line. Is there any way to get json data and remove 1 and then decode json ?

Answer (score 3):

First, there is a number "1" at the end of your json, remove it.
Second, because your json is wrapped in a [] so after you decode it, it will return an array and your result is in element 0 so your code should be:

```
$buffer = '[{"isSuccess":"true","message":"Consignment Number Valid","orderReferenceIdList":[":Succesfull"],"tracking_Details":[{"BookingDate":"02-05-2020","Destination":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Origin":"LAHORE","Shipper":"VESTURE MERCHANDISING (OTURE)","Consignee":"Syed Asad Abbas Bokhari","ServiceType":"Overnight","CNStatus":"DELIVERED","CNStatusID":"55","pieces":"1","weight":"0.5","Details":[{"DateTime":"5/5/2020 12:03:59 PM","Status":"Delivered","Location":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Detail":"Shipment has been Delivered. Delivery Date & Time May 5 2020 1:11AM and Received By: ASAD"},{"DateTime":"5/5/2020 10:03:58 AM","Status":"On Delivery","Location":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Detail":"Shipment is Out for Delivery."},{"DateTime":"5/4/2020 10:43:51 AM","Status":"On Delivery","Location":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Detail":"Shipment is Out for Delivery."},{"DateTime":"5/4/2020 10:06:57 AM","Status":"Unloading","Location":"MANDI BAHAUDDIN","Detail":"Shipment has arrived at hub."},{"DateTime":"5/4/2020 3:55:10 AM","Status":"Loading","Location":"GUJRANWALA","Detail":"Shipment has departed."},{"DateTime":"5/2/2020 11:20:44 PM","Status":"Unloading","Location":"Lahore Airport","Detail":"Shipment has arrived at hub."},{"DateTime":"5/2/2020 10:40:33 PM","Status":"Loading","Location":"KOT LAKH PAT","Detail":"Shipment has departed."},{"DateTime":"5/2/2020 8:30:52 PM","Status":"Arrived at OPS","Location":"LAHORE","Detail":"Shipment has arrived at origin facility."},{"DateTime":"5/2/2020 12:00:00 AM","Status":"Booking","Location":"LAHORE","Detail":"Shipment is booked."}]}]}]';

$data = json_decode($buffer, true);
$data = $data[0];
foreach ($data['tracking_Details'] as $a) {
    echo $a['BookingDate'];
}
```

This will return

> 02-05-2020

Comment: You could also remove the outer square brackets `[]` within the buffer, then otherwise keep your original code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works, but the issue is I am getting JSON data using courier API, and then return the data which has string 1 in the last line. Is there any way to get json data and remove 1 and then decode json ?

Comment: @MattBerry yes, use rtrim like this: `$string = rtrim($string, '1');`

Comment: @HuyTrịnh Sir can you please explain where I have to add $string = rtrim($string, '1'); ?

Comment: @MattBerry It will remove number "1" from your string, start from right, also` ltrim()` will start from begining of the string.